# Run function once every second X number of times

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to run a function X number of times, once per second.

I've tried to setTimeout within a loop, but instead of running once per second, it waits one second then runs 5 times.

```js
Press.advance = function(distance) {

  for (var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('advancing') //want it to do this once per second
    }, 1000)

  }
}
```

How can I make it run once per second for `distance` number of times?

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/24ue51b3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of `setTimeout`. Like this:

```js
var interval = null; // create a holder for the interval id
var counter = 0;    // counter for checking if `distance` has been reached
var Press = {
  advance: function(distance) {

    interval = interval || window.setInterval(() => {
      if (distance == counter++) {
        console.log('cleared');
        window.clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
        console.log('advancing') //want it to do this once per second
      }
    }, 1000);

  }
}

Press.advance(2);
```